How would I find the numerical integral of this expression with maxima quad_qags
With maxima, im not able to figure out how to do this numerical integral:
quad_qags( -psi0(x, beta)*diff(psi0(x,beta), x,2 )/2 + V(x)*psi0(x,beta)**2, x, -inf,inf);

it gives back the noun form, is there a way to do this? maple gives back an answer of -0.60....
This is the context of the problem, which comes from the variational problem in QM,  starting from a gaussian function psi0, and
computing the energy:
V(x):= -1/sqrt(1+x**2) ;
psi0(x, beta):= (sqrt(beta)*%e^(-((beta^2*x^2)/2)))/%pi^(1/4);
Energy(beta):= integrate(-psi0(x, beta)*diff(psi0(x,beta), x,2 )/2 + V(x)*psi0(x,beta)**2, x,-inf,inf); 

This is not possible to do analytically, i think, so i tried the same with quad_qags.
EDIT
Here is where i have reached with beta=1, and expand():
quad_qagi (  expand( %o28) , x, -inf, inf, 'epsrel=1d-8);
(%o35)  quad_qagi(-(integrate(psi0(x,1)*('diff(psi0(x,1),x,2))+(2*psi0(x,1)^2)/sqrt(x^2+1),x,-inf,inf)/2),x,-inf,inf,epsrel=1.0*10^-8,epsabs=0.0,limit=200)


The polygamma function is denoted psi[k](x), i.e. with the order k given as a subscript, so the digamma function is denoted psi[0](x). However, I notice that you have two arguments, x and beta. What is the definition of polygamma which you are using? Maybe you intend some function other than the polygamma function?

the function im using is a gaussian, im usinging it to study the variational problem from introductory QM.

Thanks for the additional information, it's pretty important. I see that V(x) is not yet defined. What is the definition of V(x)? Some other things that are relevant. (1) Since the interval is infinite, call quad_qagi (algorithm QAGI in the original Fortran QUADPACK) instead of quad_qags. You will need to have defined V(x) as well. (2) declare(nounify(integrate), linear) and then expand(...) where ... is an 'integrate expression containing a sum of terms. After that declaration, I get (b*'integrate(%e^-(b^2*x^2)*V(x),x,-inf,inf))/sqrt(%pi)+b^2/4 where b = beta.

I overlooked that V definition, its now there.

There is an error in the call to quad_qagi. The first argument is supposed to be the integrand, the same as the call to integrate. So you should write quad_qagi(psi0(...), etc) instead of quad_qagi(integrate(psi0(...), etc). Also, I see there is a bug in quad_qagi; sorry about, I will file a bug report. Anyway, you need to write minf instead of - inf. When I do that, I get - 0.6098866396410092 for the result from quad_qagi for beta =1, which I guess is consistent with the result you reported.

About the symbolic result, looks like Maxima can do some of it but ends up with 'integrate(exp(-x^2)/sqrt(x^2 + 1), x, minf, inf) in the result. Maybe it's possible to look up that result.

Here's what I get after fixing the call to quad_qagi and working around the problem with -inf by replacing it with minf.
(%i2) V(x):= -1/sqrt(1+x**2) ;
                                  - 1
(%o2)                 V(x) := ------------
                                        2
                              sqrt(1 + x )
(%i3) psi0(x, beta):= (sqrt(beta)*%e^(-((beta^2*x^2)/2)))/%pi^(1/4);
                                                2  2
                                            beta  x
                                          - --------
                                               2
                             sqrt(beta) %e
(%o3)       psi0(x, beta) := -----------------------
                                        1/4
                                     %pi
(%i4) Energy(beta):= quad_qagi (-psi0(x, beta)*diff(psi0(x,beta), x,2 )/2 + V(x)*psi0(x,beta)**2, x, minf, inf);
(%o4) Energy(beta) := 
          - psi0(x, beta) diff(psi0(x, beta), x, 2)
quad_qagi(-----------------------------------------
                              2
            2
 + V(x) psi0 (x, beta), x, minf, inf)
(%i5) Energy(1);
(%o5) [- 0.6098866396410092, 4.3393502531511445e-9, 270, 0]

which matches your previous result.
